# How to determine the right sword?

Tags: the-witcher-3

I am fighting enemies and using my Steel Sword for human enemies, as per the games instructions, but I've just run into a group of Ghouls and I'm unsure which sword I should be using.

The game tells me that I can tell which sword to use by looking at the health bar. A silver health bar means using the Silver Sword, and a red health bar means Steel Sword.

However I'm not sure which HP bar is which. So how can I figure out which sword to use against which enemy?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

For any **Human or common animal** you should use the **Steel Sword** and they will have a red Health Bar.

For any **Monster type** you should use the **Silver Sword**. These monsters will have  a grey/silver Health Bar.

### Examples:

Look at the Wraith (a Monster) Grey Health Bar therefore you use Silver Sword

[image: Silver Sword fight]

And now look at these bandits getting roasted. Red Health Bar so you use the Steel Sword

[image: Steel Sword Fight]

Comment: I've also discovered that if you approach an enemy without a sword drawn, Geralt will draw the correct sword for you, which is nice.

Comment: @DavidYell they are making this game to easy!! lol

Comment: @DavidYell: unless you approach a bandit fighting a ghul

Comment: What if you don't select the correct sword? Do you do less damage? No damage?

Comment: @Octopus you do way less damage.

Comment: I'm not sure its possible to use the wrong sword. After playing it last night I noticed the character sheaths his sword and draws the correct one. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @Octopus It is. I just killed a dog with a silver sword, doing 2 damage each hit. lol

Comment: @spicypumpkin. you mean a village dog? well, the character doesn't automatically draw anything for a dog, so I suppose he wouldnt automatically sheath and redraw in that case.

Comment: @Octopus nah, it was part of the story. Wild dogs.

Comment: What if my silver sword damage is 81-99 and my steel sword is 31-39? Should I still use Steel against non-monsters?